# Automatic decoration of subclass methods

Tags: python, decorator, subclass, pylance

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, arg0, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Wrapper called")
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Parent:
    @decorator
    def method(self): pass

class Child(Parent):
    def method(self, arg1, arg2):
        print("Method called")

obj = Child()
obj.method("arg0_val", "arg1_val", "arg2_val")
```

I have this Parent class that has a method that i have to decorate with *decorator*. When this method is overridden (in the Child class) I need the new method to be decorated with *decorator* as well. I can do this with init_subclass, but the problem is that Pylance will show the obj.method signature as *method(self, arg1, arg2)* instead of *method(self, arg0, *args, **kwargs)*, which is the *wrapper* signature

I tried to override the init_subclass method to apply the decorator to all subclasses' *method* like this:

```
class Parent():
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.method = decorator(cls.method)

    @decorator
    def method(self): pass

class Child(Parent):
    def method(self, arg1, arg2):
        print("Method called")

obj = Child()
obj.method("arg0_val", "arg1_val", "arg2_val")
```

the output is:

```
Wrapper called
Method called
```

and it is correct, but as I said Pylance shows the wrong signature for obj.method. I would like Pylance to know that the overridden method is now decorated

Comment: Pylance is showing the correct *static* signature for `Child.method`. `__init_subclass__` doesn't change the value of the attribute `Child.method` until runtime, making that a *dynamic* effect.

Comment: isn't there any hack to make pylance aware that the method is going to be decorated? @chepner

Comment: Consider using a private method that gets redefined by subclasses (not decorated), and only the parent class has the public decorated message that calls the private method. As in, defined the decorated method `Parent.method` which calls `self._method`, where `self._method` is defined by whatever class was instantiated. The static signature of `Parent.method` (and any subclass) will be interpreted correctly because it's decorated when the method is defined, not at instantiation, so Pylance should understand it just fine.